# speed calculation using RFID reader and arduino no

Tags: arduino, rfid

I have 2 RFID readers and 1 Arduino UNO. RFID will have 2 positions START and END. when I pass my tag through START it should start calculating time and end until it reaches the END position. START position should stop scanning immediately as soon as it scans the End position it should be vice-versa. I need the code to do this stuff.

Comment: Stackoverflow is not a free code-completion service. Spend some time to understand [millis()](https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/functions/time/millis/) function, and then try to understand the code [here](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/BlinkWithoutDelay), with some slight modification, you should be able to achieve what you want.

Comment: @hcheung I wrote the same 8 hours ago and now it was removed...

Comment: @hcheung actually you are right but I got 2 projects at the same time and my mind clogged with too much work that's why I just wanted to get written code which is not covering 5% of my project. Anyways thank you for the feedback :)